# CompletionItemProvider for snippets created in package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking to invoke a function on the use of a snippet created by package.json in a Visual Studio Code extension. I'd hope to do this by accessing the internal CompletionItemProvider or something similar.

[This](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41202) issue has a user that wants to create snippets that are similar to package.json provided snippets and he does so by creating a new CompletionItemProvider but I don't want to have to create a Provider that duplicates the suggested snippets that are already defined in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to just follow the issue linked. It was not much more effort to implement, and allowed me to create a custom function that was called on snippet use by accessing the completionItem.command property and assigning a command I made to it.